# Laravel 5.4 - middleware in construct doesn't work in ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

4 and have a problem with ajax request.

It's my JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'get-map',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

web.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::post('/create-character', 'MainController@createCharacter');
    Route::get('/main', 'MainController@main');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'check.character.exist'], function() {
        Route::get('/game', 'GameController@index');
        Route::post('/get-map', 'MapController@getMapForCharacter');
    });
});
```

__construct in MapController.php:

```
class MapController extends Controller {

    private $mapFieldId;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $character = Character::find($this->characterId);
        $this->mapFieldId = $character->map_field_id;
    }
}
```

and __construct in Controller.php:

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    protected $userId;
    protected $characterId;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            if (Auth::id()) {
                $this->userId = Auth::id();

                $character = Character::where('user_id', '=', $this->userId)->first();
                if ($character) {
                    $this->characterId = $character->id;
                }
            }

            return $next($request);
        });
    }
}
```

Works correctly in HTTP request but ajax return: ErrorException in MapController.php line 18: Trying to get property of non-object

```
$character = Character::find($this->characterId);
```

During investigate I discover that middleware in Controller.php doesn't start - parser just skip it (only for ajax request).
And i have no idea why.
Any suggestion?

Comment: I have csrf middleware in kernel.php - assigned to all web's routes.

Comment: Yes, of course. I put token in meta tag and send it with every ajax request.